# Access 2013 Report - Chr(13)+Chr(10)

Tags: report, ms-access-2013, carriage-return, linefeed, chr

I am moving a database to Access 2013. I have a report with a textbox.  In the textbox, I have:

="The individuals on the following pages have not filed a Statement of
 Economic Interests as of " & [Enter As Of Week Day and Date (Example: Monday, May 1, 2012)] & ".  Statements are due by May 1st.  Statements postmarked on or before May 1st will be accepted without a late fee.  After this date, a $15.00 late fee will be applied.  If you have any questions, please contact the Ethics Department at 815-774-6367 or by email at clerkethics@willcountyillinois.com." & Chr(13)+Chr(10) & Chr(13)+Chr(10) & "If an individual has misplaced their form, they can download a form on our website at www.thewillcountyclerk.com under Public Filings."

When I go to view the report, it brings up a box for the user to type in the date, but then brings up a chr fill in box, and Chr(13)+Chr(10) & Chr(13)+Chr(10) are not working.  What changed in 2013 that would prevent this linefeed and carriage return from working?  And how do I fix it?  I can't find anything on this subject.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just discovered - it's happening on other report textboxes.  Help!

Comment: Instead of getting a popup asking for chr, I'm getting one asking for vbCrLf.  So weird!

Comment: Tried that too - error doesn't go away. Still wants me to enter data for chr.  Even tried just using Chr(13) thinking that maybe the syntax changed when using 2 characters together (+ sign), still get error.  For the heck of it, I just tried Chr(10) - still brings up chr popup.  Tomorrow I'll try to create a form with just a textbox and the characters and see if I get the same error.  Maybe the report got corrupt when I moved it to 2013?  I will let you know.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in Access 2010.  I used `="one" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "two"` as the Control Source for a text box on my form.  It runs without asking me to supply values for either `Chr()` and displays those two words on separate lines in the text box.  Maybe the problem is limited to Access 2013.  I don't have it so can't help other than to suggest you make sure your Office install is fully updated.

Comment: Updating Office fixed the problem!  Thanks HansUp for suggesting that!

Answer (score 1):

HansUp suggested making sure Office was updated.  That worked!